# Can't find <p> in div id=footer

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

A question  related on my previous post,  about [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
This is my html code:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
 <div id="content">
    <p> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>LINK HERE</p>
</div>
```

I want to insert a link on the `<p>` of the footer.I could insert a link but the problem is, if there is another `<p>` before the div footer's `<p>`, the link will be inserted at the `<p>` in the html code. It's like it can't identify or it cannot be detected that it SHOULD ONLY SEARCH IN THE div id=footer, not the whole html code.

Here's what i've got:

```
foreach($html->find('div#footer') as $footer) 
   {
    foreach($footer->find('p') as $p) 
   {
  $footerInnerText = $p->find('p', 0)->innertext;
  $theLink = '<a href="index.php" title="" rel="home">'. $footerInnerText. '</a>';
  $html->find('p', 0)->innertext = "\n" .$theLink."\n";
  }
```

I have also tried this:

```
$e = $html->find('div#footer', 0)->find('p', 0);
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: It seems like there are parts missing from your question. I can't understand what you're asking for. Where do you want to insert a link? "I want to insert a link on the of the footer", What does that mean?

Comment: How about using regex and preg_replace. Your Regex being something similar to : "/(div id=\"footer\">).*(<p>).*(</p>).*(</div>)/"

Comment: @Flying Swissman: [NO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: i can't use regex to parse html

Comment: @BoltClock Yes it shouldn't be used for parsing a random piece of html but seeing the example I thought it was of very simple one off and predetermined piece of HTML. My response was to hasty.

Comment: I've not used the parser, but from the looks of the documentation, it supports descendant selectors, so you should just be able to do `$html->find('#footer p',0)->innertext = $theLink;`, or something similar. Also, why are you trying to insert `\n` s? Surely you'd want something like a `<br />` for HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I find Nodes in HTML a bit funky. I've seen a fair few problems with blank nodes, etc. For example in HTML the blank " " would parse as nothing, as you do not have any real text in it.

`&nbsp;` is the code you need for a space.

I believe the problem may be caused by the innerHTML of the P being blanked, therefore not existing. Have you tried by putting any values in it at all, just a random test line or the like?